# Filtering nested nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

**Hi have this array:**

```
   [ {
        "Navn": "Long Island Iced Tea",
        "Nummer": "2",
        "Glas i ml": "250",
        "Instruktioner": "",
        "a": "Hæld is i glasset",
        "b": "pynt med en skive lime",
        "Ingredienser": [
            {
                "Type": "Spiritus",
                "Del1": [
                    {
                        "Cointreau": 20
                    }
                ],
                "Del2": [
                    {
                        "Gin": 20
                    }
                ],
                "Del3": [
                    {
                        "Rom_Lys": 20
                    }
                ],
                "Del4": [
                    {
                        "Tequila": 20
                    }
                ],
                "Del5": [
                    {
                        "Vodka": 20
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "Type": "Vand/Juice",
                "Del1": [
                    {
                        "Cola": 40
                    }
                ],
                "Del2": [
                    {
                        "Sprite": 20
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "Type": "Mixer",
                "Del1": [
                    {
                        "Lime_Sirup": 20
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }]
```

Its for a Cocktailmachine.

And i want to filter it by "Del1"  searching for (example) "Rom_Lys" & "Cola" & "Vodka", and then output a new array with these specifications.

I tried searching the forums, but can't seem to find something useful. Played around with filter and includes, but cant come up with anything useful.

Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get items which are contains `Cola`, then you can use `filter` and `some` methods:

```
const filterWord = 'Cola';

const result = sampleData.filter(s => 
    s.Ingredienser.some(s => 
        s.Del1.some( e=> e[filterWord])));

console.log(result);
```

An example:

```js
let sampleData = [
{
    "Navn": "Rom & Cola/ Cuba Libre",
    "Nummer": "0",
    "Glas i ml": "200",
    "Instruktioner": "",
    "a": "Hæld is i glasset",
    "b": "pynt med en skive citron",
    "Ingredienser": [
        {
            "Type": "Spiritus",
            "Del1": [
                {
                    "Rom_Lys": 40
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Type": "Vand/Juice",
            "Del1": [
                {
                    "Cola": 100
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Type": "Mixer",
            "Del1": [
                {}
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "Navn": "Isbjørn",
    "Nummer": "1",
    "Glas i ml": "200",
    "Instruktioner": "",
    "a": "Hæld is i glasset",
    "b": "pynt med en skive citron",
    "Ingredienser": [
        {
            "Type": "Spiritus",
            "Del1": [
                {
                    "Vodka": 30
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Type": "Vand/Juice",
            "Del1": [
                {
                    "Sprite": 60
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Type": "Mixer",
            "Del1": [
                {
                    "Blå_Sirup": 30
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}];


const filterWord = 'Cola';
const result = sampleData.filter(s => s.Ingredienser.some(s => s.Del1.some( e=> e[filterWord])));
console.log(result);
```

UPDATE:

If you want to check multiple key, then you can use `hasOwnProperty` method which checks whether the object contains desired key:

```
const filters = ['Cointreau', 'Gin', 'Rom_Lys'];
const result = sampleData.filter(s =>
    s.Ingredienser.some(ingred => {
        return Object.keys(ingred).some(k=> {
            if (Array.isArray(ingred[k])) {
                return ingred[k].some(s=> filters.some(f=> {
                    return s.hasOwnProperty(f);
                }))
            }
        });
    }
));
```

And the example:

```js
let sampleData = [ {
"Navn": "Long Island Iced Tea",
"Nummer": "2",
"Glas i ml": "250",
"Instruktioner": "",
"a": "Hæld is i glasset",
"b": "pynt med en skive lime",
"Ingredienser": [
    {
        "Type": "Spiritus",
        "Del1": [
            {
                "Cointreau": 20
            }
        ],
        "Del2": [
            {
                "Gin": 20
            }
        ],
        "Del3": [
            {
                "Rom_Lys": 20
            }
        ],
        "Del4": [
            {
                "Tequila": 20
            }
        ],
        "Del5": [
            {
                "Vodka": 20
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Type": "Vand/Juice",
        "Del1": [
            {
                "Cola": 40
            }
        ],
        "Del2": [
            {
                "Sprite": 20
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Type": "Mixer",
        "Del1": [
            {
                "Lime_Sirup": 20
            }
        ]
    }
]
}];

const filters = ['Cointreau', 'Gin', 'Rom_Lys'];
const result = sampleData.filter(s =>
s.Ingredienser.some(ingred => {
    return Object.keys(ingred).some(k=> {
        if (Array.isArray(ingred[k])) {
            return ingred[k].some(s=> filters.some(f=> {
                return s.hasOwnProperty(f);
            }))
        }
    });
}
));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this is great. I realised that that i need more than this.. What if i want to filter Del1, Del2, Del3, Del4 & Del5, and and have multiple conditions like Cola & Sprite ?? I have added another Array in my top post, with more info.

Answer (score 1):

Try using following code to filter the array.

```
var filtered = arr.filter(function(unique) {
    for (var index = 0; index < unique.Ingredienser.length; index++) {
        if (unique.Ingredienser[index].Del1[0].hasOwnProperty(selectedchoice)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
});
```